# Flow Box Theorem

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am taking a course in dynamical systems and the Flow Box Theorem was presented to me. The theorem said:

> **Theorem (Flow Box)**: In the neighborhood of a regular point ($f(x_0) \neq 0$), a $C^k$ system of linear differential equations is always $C^k$-conjugated (conjugated with the corresponding homeomorphism in $C^k$) to the system of linear differential equations $y'_1=1, \, y'_2 = 0, \, \dots \, ,y'_n=0$

I am trying to prove it finding the corresponding homeomorphism restricted to the neighborhood of the regular point but I am encountering difficulties. Could anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there is missing context here. Probably a few different definitions of dynamical system are out there, for instance; what is $f$, what is the domain under consideration...

Comment: Sorry, I am editing it right now since I realized I did not mention I meant a system of linear differential equations, not a dynamical system. $f$ is describing our system ($x' = f(x)$) if I did not understand the theorem wrongly. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: The proof of a similar proposition is given in Section 4.3 of these notes https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~scheel/teaching/8501-fall18/ode_8501_script.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for the notes! It was really helpful. @whpowell96

Comment: It may be of use to others to write up your solution as an answer and accept it so that others can search for it.